# How to connect ellipses using lines in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am developing an application to visualize routers in my network. I have four or less ports in each router. I have a list of routers with their X and Y coordinates on the canvas and they look good.

I need to link them together based on the port and the next router using a line.

I have created a cable class which has two routers and a two ports. I don't know how to add them to the Itemescontrol list of my window.

```
Cable.cs
public class Cable
    {

        public Cable()
        {
        }

        public Cable(int rtr1ID, int rtr1Port, int rtr2ID, int rtr2Port)
        {
            this.rtr1ID = rtr1ID;
            this.rtr2ID = rtr2ID;
            this.rtr1Port = rtr1Port;
            this.rtr2Port = rtr2Port;
        }

        private int rtr1ID;
        public int Router1ID
        {
            get { return rtr1ID; }
            set { rtr1ID = value; }
        }

        private int rtr2ID;
        public int Router2ID
        {
            get { return rtr2ID; }
            set { rtr2ID = value; }
        }

        private int rtr1Port;
        public int Router1Port
        {
            get { return rtr1Port; }
            set { rtr1Port = value; }
        }

        private int rtr2Port;
        public int Router2Port
        {
            get { return rtr2Port; }
            set { rtr2Port = value; }
        }
    }
```

```
CableService.cs

    public class CableService
    {
        private static List<Cable> cables;

        public CableService()
        {
            cables = new List<Cable>()
            {
                new Cable{ Router1ID=1, Router1Port=1, Router2ID=2, Router2Port=4},
                new Cable{ Router1ID=2, Router1Port=3, Router2ID=5, Router2Port=2},
                new Cable{ Router1ID=5, Router1Port=3, Router2ID=3, Router2Port=2},
                new Cable{ Router1ID=4, Router1Port=4, Router2ID=1, Router2Port=1},
            };
        }

        public List<Cable> GetCables()
        {
            return cables;
        }
    }
```

```
Router.cs
public class Router : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Router()
        {
        }

        public Router(int x, int y, int id)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.id = id;
        }

        private int x;
        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value; OnPropertyChanged("X"); }
        }

        private int id;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("ID"); }
        }


        private int y;
        public int Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; OnPropertyChanged("Y"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string popName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(popName));
            }
        }

    }
```

```
RouterService.cs
public class RoutersServcie
    {
        private static List<Router> rtrList;
        public RoutersServcie()
        {
            rtrList = new List<Router>()
            {
                new Router{X=5, ID=1, Y=2},
                new Router{X=50, ID=2, Y=20},
                new Router{X=90, ID=3, Y=4},
                new Router{X=10, ID=4, Y=90},
                new Router{X=250, ID=5, Y=15},
            };
        }

        public List<Router> GetRouters()
        {
            return rtrList;
        }
```

```
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="RoutersMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RoutersMVVM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <DockPanel>
        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ItemsControl Name="icCircles">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30"  Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Canvas>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="20">
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Click me</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

```
MainWindow.xaml.cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Router> line;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            line = new RoutersServcie().GetRouters();
            icCircles.ItemsSource = line;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            icCircles.ItemsSource = null;
            int x = new Random().Next(0,500);
            int y = new Random(x).Next(0,500);
            int nextId = line.Count()+1;
            line.Add(new Router(y, x, nextId));
            icCircles.ItemsSource = line;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may draw lines in a second ItemsControl below the one with the circles.

With a view model like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PointItem> Points { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<PointItem>();
}

public class PointItem
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

the following XAML declares two ItemsControl on top of each other in a Canvas parent.

The ItemsControl for the lines uses an ItemContainerStyle with a Line element that has its X1 and Y1 properties bound to the X and Y values of the previous data item, which is easily possibly with the `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}` binding source mode. The control hides the "first" line by a Trigger on the `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` attached properties.

Note that the other control uses Path elements with an EllipseGeometry instead of Ellipse elements to make sure that the circles are centered at their respective position.

```
<Canvas>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" AlternationCount="1000000">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Line Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="3"
                          X1="{Binding X,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}"
                          Y1="{Binding Y,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}"
                          X2="{Binding X}"
                          Y2="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"  />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Path Fill="Red">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Canvas>
```

Comment: You mean I use the suggested view model to replace both of my viewmodels? but, how can i connect the routers with the cables? there must be a link between the two datasets!

Comment: Sure there must be such a link. You already have the IDs of the Routers in a Cable. Construct a view model with a "points collection" that can be used by circles and lines at the same time. The example here only shows how to draw line segments between a collection of circles, from one to the next. It should still give you an idea how to start with a more complex topology.