# Binding Coordinates to Ellipse in WPF - XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, ellipse

I have an `ItemsControl` which binds two `ObservableCollections` called `NetworkMain.Conduits` and `NetworkMain.Nodes` as lines and ellipses.

The following XAML is working well, but there are a couple of issues I want to address.

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MainPanel">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ConduitLines" Source="{Binding Path=NetworkMain.Conduits}"></CollectionViewSource>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="NodeCircles" Source="{Binding Path=NetworkMain.Nodes}"></CollectionViewSource>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cad:Conduits}">
                <Line Stroke="Yellow" 
                      StrokeThickness="2" 
                      X1="{Binding X1, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource XcoordinatesCoverter}}" 
                      X2="{Binding X2, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource XcoordinatesCoverter}}" 
                      Y1="{Binding Y1, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource YcoordinatesCoverter}}" 
                      Y2="{Binding Y2, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource YcoordinatesCoverter}}">
                </Line>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cad:Nodes}">
                <Ellipse 
                    Width="20" 
                    Height="20" 
                    Stroke="Blue"
                    Fill="Blue"
                    StrokeThickness="4">
                </Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConduitLines}}"></CollectionContainer>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource NodeCircles}}"></CollectionContainer>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas 
                    MinHeight="800" 
                    Background="Black"
                    ClipToBounds="true">
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter 
                    Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource XcoordinatesCoverter}, ConverterParameter=20}" />
                <Setter 
                    Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=OneWay,   Converter={StaticResource YcoordinatesCoverter}, ConverterParameter=20}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I don't really understand the `<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>` section which binds the Ellipse coordinates. Unfortunately it fires for both the conduits and nodes, which means I get a load of binding errors as conduits don't contain variables X and Y, as they use X1, X2, Y1, Y2.

I want to remove `<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>` and update my Ellipse `DataTemplate` to this.

```
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ConduitLines" Source="{Binding Path=NetworkMain.Conduits}"></CollectionViewSource>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="NodeCircles" Source="{Binding Path=NetworkMain.Nodes}"></CollectionViewSource>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cad:Conduits}">
               <!-- Conduits code removed from clarity -->
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cad:Nodes}">
                <Ellipse 
                    Width="10" 
                    Height="10" 
                    Stroke="Blue" 
                    StrokeThickness="4"
                    Canvas.Left ="{Binding Path=X, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource XcoordinatesCoverter}}"
                    Canvas.Top ="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource YcoordinatesCoverter}}">
                </Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
```

When I do this, all the Nodes bind with coordinates of 0,0.
I don't get any binding errors.
I'm surprised this doesn't work. Any ideas why not?

Comment: Canvas.Left/Top in the DataTemplate has no effect, because the direct parent element of the Ellipse is not the Canvas in the ItemsPanel. There is an ItemsPresenter in between, so you have to use the ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: I'd also suggest to get rid of the coordinates converter, and use a Path with an EllipseGeometry instead of an Ellipse, as it would automatically be centered. You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64965135/1136211

Comment: You may perhaps also drop Canvas.Left/Top entierely, and bind the Center property of the EllipseGeometry instead.

Comment: I understand. Thanks
So if I continue using the Ellipse, how do I make the <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle> only apply to my Nodes so avoid the databinding errors? I feel it needs a Target, but can't seem to get the Syntax right.

As for the CoordinatesConverters, the center x,y offset is quite trivial, as the conversion mainly deals with my zoom, pan etc from world coordinates to screen coordinates so I'll need to keep it the convertor anyway.

Comment: Use two ItemsControls, as shown in the linked answer. Or use ItemContainerStyleSelector, which would be kind of overkill.

Comment: Got it thanks. That does fix my binding issue, but does create a new issue regarding mouse behaviors.
If I place the ItemsControl that has the Behaviors attached first, they only fire when I'm not hovering over an item in another ItemsControl.
I therefore figured that placing the ItemsControl with the behaviors last would fix this, but instead it prevents all my behaviors from firing.
Do you know how to make the ItemsControl with behaviors attached always take precedence?

Comment: Actually nevermind, figured it out, very strangely, removing the background colour  on the canvas prevents all the behaviors from firing. Making the background transparent fixed the issue.
Thanks for the solution